# Strong consistency with Firebase real-time database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase real-time database offer **strong consistency**?

We are using Firebase real-time database in some cases as a queue:

#### Scenario 1

1. **Mobile client** writes `item` document to `/items`
2. **Server A** (Cloud Function) listens to `/items` and calls **Server B** via `POST /processItem/:itemID`
3. **Server B** fetches `items/:item` and starts processing
4. Once processed, **Server B** writes `item.processedAt = <timestamp>`

Scenario 1 logic seems to work fine, however, we started wondering if Firebase actually offers *strong consistency* and whether we can be sure that when **Server B** fetches `items/:itemID` from Firebase, the document *certainly* exists.

#### Scenario 2

1. **Server A** writes `item` document to `/items` and waits for the `.set()` operation to go through.
2. **Server A** calls **Server B** via `POST /processItem/:itemID`
3. **Server B** fetches `items/:itemID` and starts processing
4. Once processed, **Server B** writes `item.processedAt = <timestamp>`

This potentially is even more "risky" as **Server A** may call **Server B** potentially even before `child_added` event would have fired.

**Are both of these scenarios safe?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO both of these scenarios can be safe.

Scenario 1 is completely safe. Because cloud function is invoked only when firebase has written the data completely. So, you are definitely safe in scenario 1.

For scenario 2. You can go this way.

- Server A writes `item` document to `/items`
- Server A `waits for the callback` of completion from firebase.
- Server A calls Server B via `POST /processItem/:itemID`
- Server B fetches `items/:itemID` and starts processing
- Once processed, Server B writes `item.processedAt = <timestamp>`

Comment: Good clarification re scenario 2 - that is exactly what I meant. What is your "humble opinion" based on? :) 

Why I'm asking is because assuming Firebase is hosting the data on a distributed system, so having the write succeed on one instance may not necessarily guarantee it already being in sync with all the others. I.e. does write completion handler mean that write has gone through across instances - or only on one?

Comment: I think, write completion handlers are invoke immediately after writing to one instance & then write to other instances.

Comment: That would leave a possibility that Server B would fetch the data from an instance that has not synced yet. No?

Comment: I don't think so. Because, realtime database is fast enough that, all data may be replicated on all instances even before your write completion callback is executed. Anyway, the best thing is to try it out by setting up demo project.

Comment: Yep that's probably true in most cases, but is it guaranteed by design? Setting up a demo project does not prove that this could not happen.

Comment: For RTDB, it's not guaranteed by design. For Firestore, it's guaranteed by design.

Answer (score 2):

Bhavin Panara is correct. Both scenarios are "safe" in the way you've described. Once a write is acknowledged, the Realtime Database guarantees that any subsequent reads will see the result of the acknowledged write. This is also true of a Cloud Function being triggered by a write.

As you've noted, listeners are updated asynchronously, so a client listening to a location may not be updated about a write for some time.

Note that it is still possible to have race conditions even with a strongly consistent database. Consider the following scenario:

## Scenario 3

- Mobile client creates data at `/items/item1`
- Server A (Cloud Function) listens to /items and calls Server B via POST /processItem/:itemID
- Mobile client deletes data at `/items/item1`
- Server B receives request from Server A and fetches `/items/item1`, but the item has been deleted.

In these kinds of scenarios it may be helpful to fall back on [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: Can you refer to any documentation where this is mentioned? "RTDB guarantees that any subsequent reads will see the result" contradicts Bhavin's point that "For RTDB, it's not guaranteed by design".